# Pip install a python library from within a github monorepo

Tags: python, github, pip, monorepo, python-poetry

I have a monorepo github project, within which there is a python lib `repo/python-tools`, what I would like to do is `pip` install this library into another project.

Something like:

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/myorg/myrepo/python-tools
```

This is a private repository and the project is built using `poetry`.

Comment: Try using the -e parameter. pip install -e gitrepo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git#egg=python_tools&subdirectory=python-tools'
```

See the docs at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support